# How to display all posts by a user in octobrcms

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to display all posts by a user and have this in my code that works only when a user is signed in and displays all the user's posts.

```
$id =  Auth::getUser()->id;

    $this['allproducts'] = Advert::where('user_id', $id)->orderby('created_at','desc')->get();
```

I want to make this visible to all signed in or not. when i logged out and try to access the url, it throws up an error

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: There is an error with the way you are getting the user id. Please google "laravel auth get user id" as there are several questions that have already be answered that cover various different reasons why you might be getting this error.

Comment: you would have to pass the id of the user in the request or as a parameter of the route

Answer (score 0):

try using: If there is no authenticated user it gives null and it should not fetch. (If user_id does not remain null on Advert model table)

```
$id =  Auth::getUser()->id ?? null;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make this visible to all signed in or not. when i logged out and try to access the url, it throws up an error

It is not clear in this context who you refer to as a User.

If you want to make the posts of 'any user' accessible to 'any other user' then your implementation is not correct.

`Auth::getUser()` - Retrieves the signed in User from the active session - [See here](https://github.com/octobercms/library/blob/master/src/Auth/Manager.php#L159) - The error you posted is expected because after sign out, the Auth session is cleared and you cannot access the `id` property anymore.

You are basically doing `$id =  null->id;`

What you could do is list the registered users and let the site visitor / user decide which user's posts to display.

Comment: Yeah... How can i implement that?